# MySQL Query: Customer Order Value and Order Count for Multiple Date Ranges

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that works great for returning the order count and value per customer for the defined period of time.

```
SELECT
c.company, 
c.email,
SUM(o.total_value) AS ttl_order_value,
COUNT(p.order_id) AS ttl_order_count
FROM merch_orders_ist AS o
  INNER JOIN contacts_ern AS c
    ON (o.contact_id = c.contactid)
  INNER JOIN merch_payments_ist AS p
    ON (o.id = p.order_id)
WHERE DATE(p.date_of_payment) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
GROUP BY c.contactid 
ORDER BY ttl_order_value DESC
```

I need to extend this query to add two more columns that include the order totals and summed value of the orders per customer for a SECOND date range (e.g. 2015 and 2014). The result I'm looking for looks like this...

```
| company | email | ttl_order_value_2015 | ttl_order_count_2015 | ttl_order_value_2014 | ttl_order_count_2014 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have given pseudo code which requires some modification but should work based on your requirement.

Note : If syntax is not working then remove SUM(o.total_value) to o.total_value . SUM you can use by writing one simple outer query and group by

```
SELECT
c.company, 
c.email,
-- Using date put some condtions like >,< or extarct year and compare
DECODE(p.date_of_payment, '2014',SUM(o.total_value),0) AS ttl_order_value_2014,
Decode(p.date_of_payment,'2014' ,COUNT(p.order_id),0) AS ttl_order_count_2014,

DECODE(p.date_of_payment, '2015',SUM(o.total_value),0) AS ttl_order_value_2015,
Decode(p.date_of_payment,'2015' ,COUNT(p.order_id),0) AS ttl_order_count_2015,

FROM merch_orders_ist AS o
  INNER JOIN contacts_ern AS c
    ON (o.contact_id = c.contactid)
  INNER JOIN merch_payments_ist AS p
    ON (o.id = p.order_id)
WHERE DATE(p.date_of_payment) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
GROUP BY c.contactid 
ORDER BY ttl_order_value DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestions @avi . Unfortunately I'm a little lost with the DECODE statements. I'm assuming you're saying I should use sub-selects in that part of the MySQL statement?

Comment: @Spencer what I meat was to write simple query using Decode or Case Statement and then on top of that query write SUM and Count function.  Something like Select A,B, sum(c),Count(D) from( Select a,b,decode(date ,2014,C,0),decode(date,2014,D,0)).... from table1...) group by A,B